# Way to read send custom fields and extra fields with credit card details in brain tree

Tags: credit-card, braintree

Is there any example scenario for sending additional fields with braintree credit card payment. I tried to send cardholder-name and somecustom field. But It can't be read in the Transaction after transaction request.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Checkout the [Braintree documentation of passing custom fields in a Transaction.sale()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#custom-fields) call, below.

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :amount => "10.00",
  :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client,
  :custom_fields => {
    :custom_field_one => "value one",
    :custom_field_two => "value two"
  }
)

if result.success?
  result.transaction.custom_fields
  #=> {:custom_field_one => "value one", :custom_field_two => "value two"}
end
```

Note, you need to configure all custom fields in the Control Panel. You can [find a detailed walkthrough in the Braintree docs](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/custom-fields).

Also, you mentioned sending `cardholder-name`. It's unclear to me whether you actually want to use the [`cardholder_name`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#credit_card.cardholder_name) property of the [`credit_card`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#credit_card) object, or, if you simply want to store the name of a customer. If you want to do the latter, you could include the [`customer` object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#customer) with the `first_name` and `last_name` properties in your Transaction.sale() call. This will create a [customer](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/) in your Vault as well as a [payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/).